# Seperating Custom Post Search Results

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I have a site that has a few custom post types. When a customer searches it shows a combination of all the different posts. I'd like to segment the two on the same page resulting in something that looks like the example below. Any help would be appreciated.

> **Showing results for: really cool search**
> **Video Management**
> from a central location. Radius offers
> interactive map capability, and
> multiple monitor support. Designed for
> a multiple monitor environmen...
> http://openeye.net/products/software/video-management
>
> ---
>
> **Knowledge Base Entries:**
> **Repairing your device**
> from a central location. Radius offers
> interactive map capability, and
> multiple monitor support. Designed for
> a multiple monitor environmen...
> http://openeye.net/?faq=video-management-repair

Example of my loop from loop-search.php

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
<h4 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'twentyten' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<?php if ( is_archive() || is_search() ) : // Only display excerpts for archives and search. ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail; ?>
        <?php if (function_exists('relevanssi_the_excerpt')) { relevanssi_the_excerpt(); }; ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_permalink(); ?></a>
    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail; ?>
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_permalink(); ?></a>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

my changes to search.php

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : $posts_per_page = 20; ?>
    <span style="font-size:18px;" class="page-title"><?php printf( __( 'Showing results for: %s', 'twentyten' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' ); ?></span>
    <?php
    /* Run the loop for the search to output the results.
     * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
     * called loop-search.php and that will be used instead.
     */
     get_template_part( 'loop', 'search' );
    ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <div id="post-0" class="post no-results not-found">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentyten' ); ?></h2>
        <div class="entry-content">
    <?php if (function_exists('relevanssi_didyoumean')) {
        relevanssi_didyoumean(get_search_query(), "<p>Sorry, but nothing matched your search criteria. Please try again with some different keywords. Or you can also try ", "</p>", 5);
    }?>
            <?php related_searches(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    </div><!-- #post-0 -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and I found something interesting on relevanssi site. You can find it here [Separating posts by post type](http://www.relevanssi.com/knowledge-base/separating-posts-by-post-type/) Actually I'm not able to make it work but hopefully this is the better solution using Relevanssi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can group posts by type using `posts_groupby` filter hook:

```
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'group_by_post_type' );
function group_by_post_type( $groupby )
{
  global $wpdb;
  if( !is_search() ) {
    return $groupby;
  }
  $mygroupby = "{$wpdb->posts}.post_type";
  if( !strlen(trim($groupby))) {
    // groupby was empty, use ours
    return $mygroupby;
  }
  // wasn't empty, append ours
  return $groupby . ", " . $mygroupby;
}
```

Then in your loop of do something like this:

```
$last_type="";
$typecount = 0;
while (have_posts()){
    the_post();
    if ($last_type != $post->post_type){
        $typecount = $typecount + 1;
        if ($typecount > 1){
            echo '</div>'; //close type container
        }
        // save the post type.
        $last_type = $post->post_type;
        //open type container
        switch ($post->post_type) {
            case 'post':
                echo "<div class=\"post container\"><h2>posts search result</h2>";
                break;
            case 'page':
                echo "<div class=\"page container\"><h2>pages search result</h2>";
                break;
            case 'custom_type_name':
                echo "<div class=\"custom container\"><h2>custom post type search result</h2>";
                break;
            //add as many as you need.
        }
    }

    //...
    // do your loop 
    //...
}
```

Comment: I seem to be having a bit of trouble getting this working, it doesn't return any data from the loop. I'm using Relevanssi, but I don't believe it has an effect on my loop. I'll update the post with what I'm doing on my end. Thanks again Bainternet!

Comment: Zach, any updates on getting this working? I'm looking for something very similar and I am also using Relevanssi.

Comment: I was able to get this working - Thank you Bainternet!

Comment: When I use your groupby-code I only get one result of each post type.

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to add that while @bainternet's up-voted solution is great, it can break the Media Library's search function. This problem, and a simple solution, both appear [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cant-search-in-media-library).

The simple solution is to add this conditional around the code above:

```
if (!is_admin()) {
  [your code here]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this working after tweaking the above solution a bit. First the filter need to be changed to retrieve more that 1 result:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'group_by_post_type', 10, 2);
function group_by_post_type($orderby, $query) {
global $wpdb;
if ($query->is_search) {
    return $wpdb->posts . '.post_type DESC';
}
// provide a default fallback return if the above condition is not true
return $orderby;
}
```

Then the loop needed to be tweaked a little. I wanted to style my results differently with different information, so I added a further conditional.

```
<?php if(have_posts()) : ?>

<?php   
$last_type="";
$typecount = 0;
while (have_posts()) :
the_post();
if ($last_type != $post->post_type){
    $typecount = $typecount + 1;
    if ($typecount > 1){
        echo '</div><!-- close container -->'; //close type container
    }
    // save the post type.
    $last_type = $post->post_type;
    //open type container
    switch ($post->post_type) {
        case 'post':
            echo "<div class=\"postsearch container\"><h2>Blog Results</h2>";
            break;
        case 'product':
            echo "<div class=\"productsearch container\"><h2>Product Search   Results</h2>";
            break;

    }
} 
?>

    <?php if('post' == get_post_type()) : ?>
     <li class="post"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
<?php endif; ?>

  <?php if('product' == get_post_type()) : ?>
 <li class="product"><?php the_title(); ?></li>
  <?php endif; ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php else : ?>
<div class="open-a-div">
<p>No results found.</p>    

<?php endif; ?>       

</div><!-- throw a closing div in -->
```

Basically the only changes are the filter and the closing div that was omitted at the end. That and the "No results found." This is working on my site.